# 'default' is ont in your gulpfile

Tags: css, gulp

I don't know what's wrong with my file. I've been at this for a while now. THe other user's gulp problem doesn't really help me with mine. THanks in advance.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths: ['scss'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});



// gulp.task('sass', function() {
//     gulp.src('sass/main.sass')
//         .pipe(sass({ includePaths: ['sass'] }))
//         .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
// })


gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(["css/*.css", "js/*.js"], {
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});


gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {

    gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("sass/*.sass", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('*.html', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. If you try gulp browser-sync for example, does it work?

Comment: Try gulp default not gulp 'default'.  Or just gulp as your command.

Comment: neither suggestion is working for me and I am in the project file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'its not working', tell us more : if you just try gulp or gulp browser-sync, what error do you receive?

Comment: I just found the problem. I'm just learning abotu gulp and I had another "gulp" file in the root directory with nothing on it. The code above was on 'gulpfile.js' in my js folder. Everything is good now, Thanks for trying to help